# is it possible to Convert NSString to NSData?

Tags: objective-c, types, nsdata

I Have Converted NSData to NSString, now i would like to Convert back the NSString to NSData.

Here is where i converted the NSData to String

```
NSData *actualData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:msgdata];
NSLog(@"Actual data Before converted to a string: %@", actualData);

NSString *test = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", actualData];
```

Is it possible to take the NSString back to NSData format?

Edited:

Code for Encoding my NSData variable:

```
NSMutableData *actualData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:msgdata];
NSLog(@"Actual data Before converted to a string: %@", actualData);

NSString *test = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", actualData];
NSLog(@"Pre encoded data: %@", test);
NSData *plainData = [test dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Mid encoded data variable: %@", plainData);
NSString *base64String = [plainData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```

Code For Decoding:

```
NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64String options:0];
NSLog(@"check the decoded data: %@", decodedData);
NSString *decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decodedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Decoded String Afterwards: %@", decodedString);
```

Can i go even further than this and get it back to the origional actualData Value??

Comment: It is: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1416696-datausingencoding?language=objc

Comment: this will give me an encoded value not the original NSData value.

Comment: Actually `initWithFormat` is the wrong API to convert Data to String. Usually readable strings are always encoded.

Comment: ok let me edit my question so you get a clear picture of what i am trying to do

Comment: @vadian check that out i was using the initWithFormat so that i could get a readable string before i started encoding, but i don't know if this is logical, since i am new with using objective-c

Comment: You haven't explained how the string should represent the data.  One way is base-64 for example.  Or perhaps the data is UTF-8.  However you cannot just convert data to a string as strings cannot represent the values 0-255 without some sort of encoding rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to convert `Data` to `String` and vice versa.

– If *data* represents a readable string use NSString's `initWithData:encoding:` and `dataUsingEncoding:`. The `encoding` value of both must match.

– If *data* represents raw data (for example an image) use NSData's `base64EncodedStringWithOptions:` and `initWithBase64EncodedString:options:`.

But never use NSString's `initWithFormat` and pass an `NSData` object. That's pointless.